# How to start on modifying the admin portion of Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to modify the Magento admin system to allow authenticated users to find products via manufacturer and category.

So, basically, either two `select` elements which an `option` for each manufacturer/category, or two autocomplete boxes.

What I need help with is how to get started. I can guess I edit the views to add the controls (which I've figured out how to do), but then where would I add the code to allow this functionality? Do I modify queries or modify how the model gets the products?